# R: Find product codes using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, r, expression, gsub

So I have a list of product item descriptions. I have loaded this into R. Most of these descriptions are utter nonsense and we are trying to extract a decent item code from them.

Instead of going through it line by line, can I use a regular expression in R to create a new vector that will only have integer values from the list?

I have most of the code now

```
JJ <- read.csv2(file.choose(),header= TRUE)
JJ$X <- gsub(pattern = "[0-9]+", replacement = "", 
    x = JJ$LGY_DHB_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

But I am unsure what to put in the replacement argument.

Comment: You most likely can, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

you can try replacing non (`^`) numerical (`[:digit:]`) characters with empty string :

```
gsub("[^[:digit:]]*", "", 'PRIVATE CONTRACT INV 710456354')
[1] "710456354"
```

but this wont work if you have more than one numeric in your string:

```
gsub("[^[:digit:]]*", "", 'PRIVATE 123 CONTRACT INV 710456354')
[1] "123710456354"
```

You could try to find the longest numercial in each string:

```
JJ <- data.frame(LGY_DHB_ITEM_DESCRIPTION=c('PRIVATE CONTRACT INV 710456354', 'PRIVATE 123 CONTRACT INV 710456354'))
m <- gregexpr("[0-9]*", JJ$LGY_DHB_ITEM_DESCRIPTION)
all_m <-  regmatches(JJ$LGY_DHB_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, m)
JJ$X <- mapply(FUN =function(stri,idx) stri[idx],all_m, sapply(lapply(all_m,nchar),which.max))
JJ
            LGY_DHB_ITEM_DESCRIPTION         X
1     PRIVATE CONTRACT INV 710456354 710456354
2 PRIVATE 123 CONTRACT INV 710456354 710456354
```

Comment: Should that be "[0-9][0-9]*" to ensure that it matches an integer with at least one digit?  (Or "[0-9]+", I don't know R, only regexes)

Comment: `grep` doesn't extract anything (and no, i'm not the downvoter)

Comment: oups @thelatemail, too quick, and thx to be a commenter rather than downvoter

Comment: @eewanco that sounds about right, but I don't know what to put in the replace argument.